# connect to GCP from my laptop using SSH certificate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, certificate, google-cloud-sql

I am setting up a GCP Cloud SQL instance with postgreSQL and want to connect to it from my laptop using Python and a software called QGIS. I travel a lot and my IP changes all the time so using IP whitelisting is a pain. Is there a way to have something that is tied to the device? For example using certificates?

Answer (score 1):

Install the Google Cloud SDK. The CLI `gcloud` can set up an IAP TCP tunnel that uses the instance name. Then you can connect with any software that uses TCP/IP addressing.

```
gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel INSTANCE_NAME INSTANCE_PORT --local-host-port=localhost:LOCAL_PORT
```

For more information consult this document:

[Using Cloud IAP for TCP forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding)

Comment: As mentioned in the answer by @tranvu-xuannhat, this solution can work if your database is running on a simple Compute Engine instance. It does not work for the managed Cloud SQL service.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from [John Hanley](https://serverfault.com/a/988323/542552) is perfect and recommended for GCE VM instance.

However, since the OP is mentioning about connecting to a Cloud SQL instance from QGIS software, I would say we could not do it that way.

I would recommend a solution that I haven't try but fairly possible.

We will only allow private IP connection to the Cloud SQL instance from the console. Then we can deploy the Cloud SQL Proxy on a VM in a same network and connect to CloudSQL using service account.

Anytime the OP want to use QGIS, he could just need to:

- start the CloudSQL proxy in the VM, for example:

  `./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=myProject:us-central1:cloudSQLInstance=tcp:5432 &`
- then create the [General TCP Tunneling](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#general_tcp_tunneling) to connect from his machine to the CloudSQL proxy port.

  `gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel vmInstance 5432 \
  --local-host-port=localhost:ANY_PORT`

  `psql -h localhost -p ANY_PORT`